# xCode 4.2 iOS5 interfaceBuilder cannot tap on a button that is laid out in the IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, layout, interface-builder, uibutton

I've ran into a weird issue lately:

I have a 320 x640 UIView within a UIScrollView. I've manually positioned buttons throughout the view and assigned actions to them. One of the buttons has a center at [x,y]: [287,440]. The button is 60x60.

I can tap all other buttons and controls located as low as Y = 353.

I see that the button is located on the same level as all of my other buttons, within the same view as them.

What could be causing my button to be completely untappable? I have another controller, which is also "tall", and there buttons located "off screen" are tappable. [If I move the button up to the level of other buttons, it works as expected.]

Here's the scroll view code:

```
  self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 640);
```

Comment: Make sure "User Interaction Enabled" is checked for that button in Interface Builder.  Make sure you've set the button's target and action.

Comment: Whenever you have a complex layout with multiple subviews, it's often helpful to give each view a different semi-transparent background color. This will make it immediately apparent if you have some other subview over top of your button. Remember also that by default, you can add a subview to a view such that the subview is outside the bounds of the view. The subview will be fully visible but not clickable (since its superview won't pick up any touches, these touches cannot be passed on to the subview).

Comment: @rob: he said the button is tappable if he moves it up around the other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Something is covering it. Try looping over all subviews and printing origin.y relative to scrollview origin.y, and then height plus relative position.  Do this in viewWillAppear. Be aware that autoresizing behavior can kick in right after viewDidLoad and fool you. That is what happened to me earlier.  There will be an overlap somewhere.

Can post code example later from home if this doesn't get you through it.